# For any given function $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$, what is $\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have a general function assuming the following integral does exist
$$\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx.$$
How do I solve it? I have tried to split it up from $0$ to $0.5$ and from $0.5$ to $1$, but I don't know what to do next.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You mean 'how do I find an antiderivative'?

Comment: Or rather, "how do I calculate this sum ?"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Hint.** Set $\displaystyle I=\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx$. By the change of variable $x \to1-x$ you get that
$$
I=\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx.
$$
Then observe that
$$
I+I=\int_0^1\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx+\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx=1
$$ giving easily $$I=\frac12.$$

Comment: Thx, the only thing I don't understand is how you can set u=1-x without getting a minus in front of the integral because of the du/dx=-1

Comment: @netwon1227 Recall that $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$. So the minus sign disappears: $\int_1^0=-\int_0^1$. Thanks.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't get the second line: I=\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx.. You have changed the variable: u \to1-x. Shouldn't it be I=-\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx because du/dx=-1 ?

Comment: @netwon1227 Don't forget to switch $0$ and $1$, so you rather obtain $$-\int_1^0\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx $$ which gives $$\int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}dx $$ Right?

Comment: @netwon1227 Observe that $1-0=1$ and $1-1=0$ ...

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I didn't get it. Thank you, very helpful answer.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$$
u = 1-x,\qquad x = 1-u
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)\,dx}{f(x)+f(1-x)} = \int_1^0 \frac{f(1-u)(-du)}{f(1-u)+f(u)} = \int_0^1\frac{f(1-x)\,dx}{f(1-x)+f(x)}.
$$
What the *sum* of the first and last integrals is, is clear.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use $I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

$I+I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]\ dx$